# Selenium webdriver upload file window on mac or Linux

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a page that have two upload buttons I would like to automate. I see some answers using send_key with an input element. However my element is a button and with ng-click event to open the upload file window. Is the send_key method still works for this scenario?

Comment: It is too broad to answer, please add more details. I am pretty sure there is a hidden file input somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Will need details for the events after you click upload button. Do you want to upload the document from your desktop or do you upload the document from server? Kindly provide the details, so that we can assist further.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had found out the answer for my own question. Simply just send_key. The reason that I didn't make it work was I'm looking at a wrong place on the page.